# How Do I Escape / Exit a route in Express on the same request?

Tags: javascript, express

I organized my routing so that it would cascade down based on permissions, which for the app I was building made a lot of sense. My reasoning all makes sense, it's just an issue of whether it's possible to do this in Express.js.

If the user is a "Project Manager" than they can't access the Admin route. They should only be able to access the ManagerRouter and the DeveloperRouter.

[image: routing]

**I'm having trouble escaping the route. This is the code for doing that. It does execute the 'else' statement but it doesn't escape anything:**

[image]

Is there a way to do this in Express?

Answer (score 1):

I may have found the answer, **next('route')** and **next('router')** only work with **app.method() or essentially app.VERB()**

So after organizing my routes, I essentially used **app.all('*')**, which in this case is serving the same function as **app.use()** but **next('route')** and **next('router')** **will now work.**

I organized it a bit to use **router.all('*')**. But for another person's use case, you could **just use app.all('*')** Here's the final product:

[image]